# Rails 3.2 Refactoring With Rubycritic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my **r_grids_controller.rb**

```
before_filter -> {find_rgrid_by_user params[:user_id]}, only: [:update_admin_call, :update_admin_email,
                                                             :update_admin_offline, :update_onboarded]

.........
def update_admin_email
  old_admin_email = @rgrid.admin_email
  @rgrid.update_attribute('admin_email', !old_admin_email)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'update_checkbox', :locals => {:checkbox_name => "email_#{params[:user_id]}"}}
  end
end

def update_admin_call
  old_admin_call = @rgrid.admin_call
  @rgrid.update_attribute('admin_call', !old_admin_call)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'update_checkbox', :locals => {:checkbox_name => "call_#{params[:user_id]}"}}
  end
end

def update_admin_offline
  old_admin_offline = @rgrid.admin_offline
  @rgrid.update_attribute('admin_offline', !old_admin_offline)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'update_checkbox', :locals => {:checkbox_name => "offline_#{params[:user_id]}"}}
  end
end

def update_onboarded
  old_onboarded = @rgrid.onboarded
  @rgrid.update_attribute('onboarded', !old_onboarded)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'update_checkbox', :locals => {:checkbox_name => "onboarded_#{params[:user_id]}"}}
  end
end

private

def find_rgrid_by_user(user_id)
  @rgrid = RGrid.find_by_user_id(user_id)
end
```

using RubyCritic, it says me that these 4 blocks are 'DuplicateCode'. However, I don't know how can I refactor this to keep it DRY.

Somebody has an idea? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can reuse the same parts and just call the methods, so:

```
def update attribute
  old_value = @rgrid.send(attribute)
  @rgrid.update_attribute(attribute, ! old_value)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'update_checkbox', :locals => {:checkbox_name => "#{attribute}_#{params[:user_id]}"}}
  end
end
```

But it is better to protect or to limit attributes just with sepcified list: `%w(admin_email admin_call admin_offline onboarded)`, so insert this at the beginning od the method.

```
unless %i(admin_email admin_call admin_offline onboarded).include?(attribute)
   raise
end
```

Then call in a controller:

```
update :onboarded
```

Comment: Really, it's perfect! Do you have some suggests (websites, blogs, articles,...) to help me refactor these problems, like the warnings with Rubycritic? It will be very helpful for my learning :)